# How to import a generic selenium devtool network version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-java

Im using selenium-java 4.6.0 and Im capturing network traffic.When I try to import the selenium class for 'Network', I get several options :

- org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v107.network.Network;
- org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v106.network.Network;
- etc...

Is there a way to select always the last version available? Or another way to not to change with each new release the import version?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same question a while back. Here is the answer I got back from Jim Evans (one of the Selenium developers):

> those will change with every release. If you choose to use the raw DevTool protocol API, you’re tying yourself to a *specific* version of Chrome. This is the same reason that CDP-based automation libraries like Puppeteer tie their releases to specific versions of Chrome. Selenium provides version-agnostic APIs for common things that many people want to use CDP for, like network request/response interception and manipulation. If you find those APIs lacking, it would be instructive to know your use case, and how common it is.

[source](https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/dF48mBon2x8/m/mRQFw2FkCAAJ)

Comment: Yes, I see but the didnt answer which library we need to use, he said "Selenium provides version-agnostic APIs for common things that many people want to use CDP"

Comment: @matias Well, it's all the ones that do not have a `vXX` in the package name. Some [examples are here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/).

Comment: aha but I need to specific the version on the import and the options available only have vXX

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think you can do this by specifying a specific import in class:
`import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v85.network.Network;`

With one version import it's no way that it take some other version.